# Parsing functionality in shell script

Tags: shell, parsing, unix

If I am trying to look up which host bus is the hard drive attached to, I would use

```
ls -ld /sys/block/sd*/device
```

it returns

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Oct 18 14:52 /sys/block/sda/device -> ../../../1:0:0:0
```

Now if I want to parse out that "1" in the end of the above string, what would be the quickest way?

Sorry I am very new to shell scripting, I can't make full use of this powerful scripting language.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split with slashes, select last field, split it with colons and select first result:

```
ls -ld /sys/block/sd*/device | awk -F'/' '{ split( $NF, arr, /:/ ); print arr[1] }'
```

It yields:

```
1
```

Comment: can you explain "{ split( $NF, arr, /:/ ); print arr[1] }"?

Comment: Yes. It's very simple. `$NF` is the last field (`1:0:0:0`) and `arr` is an array variable where it saves each part split, so I access to the first one.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
$ ls -ld /sys/block/sd*/device |  grep -oP '\d+(?=:\d+:\d:\d+)'
0
2
3
```

or

```
$ printf '%s\n' /sys/block/sd*/device |
    xargs readlink -f |
    grep -oP '\d+(?=:\d+:\d:\d+)'
```

and if you want only the first occurence :

```
grep ...-m1 ...
```